# Crystal Reports Formula Fields Line Graph

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports, linegraph

In Crystal Reports for Visual Studio I want to create a line chart that will have on the X axis Observation date and on the Y the sum of major divided by the sum of NoStalks in decimal eg below on the **2nd** picture the first graph point should be 2/69 = 2.89 instead its giving me 4.61 for all other points. I attached first image of my results data.

[image]

I created a formula field SUM({GetIPDMData;1.Major})/SUM({GetIPDMData;1.NoStalks})*100

That is Inchange of Observation Date and the show value (above formula field). Now this does not give me what i want and instead gives me this:

[image]

Can some one give some insight as how to achieve the appropriate graph

Answer (score 0):

Group the report by ObservationDate and change the formula to
SUM({GetIPDMData;1.Major}, {GetIPDMData;1.ObservationDate}) / SUM({GetIPDMData;1.NoStalks}, {GetIPDMData;1.ObservationDate}) * 100

The 2nd argument in aggregate expressions tells Crystal you wish to sum for the current group rather than for the whole report.

Comment: I added ObservationGroupd to the report then edited my Formula Field with your exact code then under chart expert Data tab for show value i added the Formula Field.   This does not render a graph. I notice you have : {GetIPDMData;1.ObservationDate}) / SUM({GetIPDMData;1.NoStalks} Are we dividing a date by integer?